# MATLAB Cell Array - Replacing Numbers in Different Columns with Strings

Tags: matlab, indexing, cell-array

I am working in Matlab.
I created a matrix and then a cell array based on that matrix:
`A = randi([1 5], 5, 5);`
`B = num2cell(A);`

I want to replace the numbers in B with different strings based on A's columns.

For example, where column
`A(:,1) == 1`
replace with 'Cat' and
`A(:,2) == 1` replace with 'Dog'

If
`A = [ 1  2  1  3  5; 2  1  5  1  4; 1  1  2  5  1; 5  5  3  4  1; 1  1  2  5  2]`

Then I want
`B = [ Cat   2  1  3  5; 2    Dog  5  1  4; Cat  Dog  2  5  1; 5     5  3  4  1; Cat  Dog  2  5  2]`

I have tried
`B(A(:, 1) == 1) = {'Cat'}` and
`B(A(:,2) == 1) = {'Dog'}`  but everything keeps getting placed in B's first column.  I can't figure out the indexing.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: You need to add an index for the column in the cell array.

Comment: How?  I have tried several ways and keep getting errors.

Comment: `B(A(:,1) == 1, 1) = {'Cat'}` should work. Or even `B(A(:,1) == 1, 1) = 'Cat'`

Comment: Thank you, `B(A(:,1) == 1, 1) = {'Cat'}` and `B(A(:,2) == 1, 2) = {'Dog'}` did the trick!